# Jquery Filer Image Upload issue

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am using JqueryFiler to add images but i am having issue with preview, image is not loading in preview, please see screenshots.
[View Screenshot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiVho.png2

Please see my code:

```js
uploadFile: {
            url: base_url+"/ajax_upload_file?width="+thumbnail_width+"&height="+thumbnail_height+"&images_limit="+images_limit,
            data: null,
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data, el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
                $('#attached_file').val(data);
                var string = $('#attached_files').val();
                $('#attached_files').val(addtoString($('#attached_files').val(),data));
            },
            error: function(el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Error</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            statusCode: null,
            onProgress: null,
            onComplete: null
        },
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please? It should be easier to detect and resolve your problem

Comment: i have added code now please review. thanks

Comment: what does return data? can u do a **console.log(data)**

Comment: see this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiVho.png2